# I want to change the API request based on button click. The number in the API changes and different data loads but component does not rerender

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a crypto coin API which gives results based on page number. So I want to change the number in the call based on pagination buttons. The number changes but the data does not reload.

```
const [activePage, setActivePage] = useState(8);
  const getCoinsData = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await Axios.get(
        `https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/markets?vs_currency=usd&per_page=100&page=${activePage}&sparkline=true&price_change_percentage=1h%2C24h%2C7d`
      );
      setData(response.data);
      setLoading(false);
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  };



  useEffect(() => {
    getCoinsData();
  }, []);
```

This is the pagination structure

```
<div className="home-pagination">
        <div
          className={
            activePage === 1 ? "pagination-button active" : "pagination-button"
          }
          onClick={() => setActivePage(1)}
        >
          1
        </div>
        <div
          className={
            activePage === 2 ? "pagination-button active" : "pagination-button"
          }
          onClick={() => {
            setActivePage(2);
          }}
        >
          2
        </div>
</div>
```

How do I re-render the component so the new data loads based on new page number.v

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your state is updating properly n every page click. The only thing you need to do is call the API again.
You can handle it in useEffect

```
  useEffect(() => {
    getCoinsData();
  }, [activePage]);
```

by adding `activePage`  as a dependency to useEffect, it will call getCoinsData API  on every activePage change

Comment: Thanks man! Worked immediately!